Determinar que boton o input ha presionado el usuario javascript
estoy haciendo un crud con html, php, css y algo de javascript (soy inexperta verdaderamente), necesito previsualizar imagenes, pero por el momento busco la manera de determinar que boton o en este caso input file ha sido presionado por el usuario, esto con la finalidad de determinar en que fila se tiene que previsualizar la imagen.
He probado un video y la solucion de la pagina parzibyte pero no he logrado conseguir que al menos me diga que boton he clickeado.
Mi input file
<input type='file' name='foto_e".$contador."' id='foto_e".$contador."' class='filecrud'>

El script que tengo colocado al final del documento html
<script>
const botones = document.querySelectorAll('.filecrud');
const cuandosehaceclick =function(evento){
    console.log('Haz hecho click en un boton')
}

botones.forEach(boton = >{
    boton.AddEventListener("click", cuandosehaceclick);
})
</script>

No se si sea que estoy ligando mal jquery asi que tambien agradeceria si esta correcta la manera en la que lo esoy haciendo
Antes del title tengo esto
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

dentro del body al inicio tengo esto
<script src = './jquery-3.7.1/js'></script>

Por el momento deseo que me ayuden a que al menos en la consola me diga que he hecho click, lo demas creo que ya tengo una idea :(

Te has equivocado en algo muy minúsculo.
El método correcto es addEventListener, no AddEventListener (JavaScript es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas).
Y en el foreach, tiene que ser => sin espacios.
La consola del navegador seguro te arrojó los errores, la revisaste ?


const botones = document.querySelectorAll('.filecrud');
const cuandosehaceclick = function(evento) {
    console.log('Has hecho click en el botón con ID:', evento.target.id);
}

botones.forEach(boton => {
    boton.addEventListener("click", cuandosehaceclick);
});
<input type='file' name='foto_e1' id='foto_e1' class='filecrud'>
<input type='file' name='foto_e2' id='foto_e2' class='filecrud'>
<input type='file' name='foto_e3' id='foto_e3' class='filecrud'>
<input type='file' name='foto_e4' id='foto_e4' class='filecrud'>
<input type='file' name='foto_e5' id='foto_e5' class='filecrud'>




Vaya, nunca lo hubiera descifrado. Muchas gracias
